# Java: Prepare for forced shutdown

Tags: java, shutdown, shutdown-hook

I am making an application in Java where I want to always have the data saved to a file with minimal saving operations. In other words, whenever the app is closed or an exception is thrown, it will first attempt to save. The one problem: the POWER BUTTON. When a user holds the power button to a computer, it forces the OS to shut down. Now, how exactly do I make Java detect an incoming shut-down, or will the JVM shut the system first (therefore calling shutdown hooks)?

Comment: That button operates on the hardware level, so... no.

Comment: @JanDvorak Alright. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: If the OS is shut down normally while the application is still running, you can actually make use of a shutdown hook.  Take a look at [shutdown hooks](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).  But yeah like @Jan said, nothing you can do about power loss.

Comment: Here is a way you can put a shutdown hook for your application: `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() { ... } `. In case of "power off" it will not be triggered so I can suggest you to save your data on a regular basis using some scheduler.

Comment: The other thing you may not like: killing applications also doesn't trigger shutdown hooks. But at least data in the write buffer of a disk isn't lost. Your unflushed application level buffers though are.

Comment: All very useful information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I summarize here what was mostly already written in the comments.

What normally happens when the user presses the power button for more than 4 seconds, is that the bios will cut power to the mainboard and all peripherals.

**There is no way software (OS or user software) can react to this situation.**

What may happen is that hard drives would flush any hardware buffer and park the heads in a safe position for transportation but it may as well not happen and the programmer has anyway no way to control that.

What you may react to regular system shutdown using [shutdown hooks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))